# как правильно вернуть результат запроса из блока try catch в typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch, try-catch, any

Есть get запрос и async функция, мне нужно вернуть результат запроса из функции, объявить переменную result внутри блока try catch нельзя, потому что return в конце функции её не увидит, поэтому я объявляю result до блока try catch и это работает.
Но я слышал что тип any нужно избегать, так как теряется смысл использования TypeScript, поэтому у меня появился такой вопрос - допустимо ли с точки зрения typescript так объявлять переменную result без инициализации и указания типа ,ведь result здесь имеет тип any?

```js
export const getResult = async (URL): Promise<ResponseObject> => {
  let result;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(URL);
    result = await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return result;
};
```

Comment: Как вы планируете узнать, из результата работы функции, успешный был вызов или нет?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что можно из try сделать return если успешный результат, и return из catch если не успешный ? Я пробовал возвращать из catch null, но потом появляются проблемы из-за этого null'а в другой функции, которая использует эту

Comment: в другой функции я делаю
  const requests = someArray.map((item) => {
    return getResult(item);
  });
  const results = Promise.all(requests);
и получается, что если из catch возвращать null то в results будут попадать null'ы.
А если пытаться в map их отсеять, то я не знаю что вернуть из map если из getResult пришел null.
Есть вариант сохранять их с nullaми, а потом фильтровать, но мне кажется тоже не очень хорошо так делать

Comment: как ты отличаешь ошибочное завершение от неошибочного? Что ты хочешь вернуть в случае ошибки? Тип result ты можешь установить `ResponseObject`

Comment: если я поставлю result тип ResponseObject, то получается ошибка там где return result
Variable 'result' is used before being assigned.ts(2454)

Comment: а как вообще правильно делать, что нужно возвращать в ошибочном и неошибочном случае?
Я могу вернуть result из try и null из catch, и потом везде при вызове функции делать проверки, что там не null возвращается, так делать нормально? А если таких функций будет много, то нужно каждую так обрабатывать везде где она используется, или есть способ лучше?

Comment: Ваш код текущей функции можно сократить до `return fetch(URL).then((res) => res.json())`

Comment: сократить можно, но что тогда вернуть из catch ?

Comment: Вам не нужен он в данной функции, если только вы не захотите вернуть при ошибке все равно какой-то результат.

Comment: а что будет при ошибке если убрать catch ?

Comment: Попробуйте и узнаете)

Comment: зачем вообще он тогда нужен если можно и без него ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Лучше определить тип возвращаемого значения:

```
interface ResponseObject {
  // ...
}

export const getResult = async (URL: string): Promise<ResponseObject> => {

  let result: ResponseObject = {} as ResponseObject;  
//или let result: ResponseObject | null = null;

  try {
    // ...
  } catch {
    // ... 
  }

  return result;
}
```

Инициализация со значением по умолчанию позволяет сохранить типизацию и избежать ошибки

2)Или использовать дженерики:

```
export const getResult = async <T>(URL: string): Promise<T> => {

  let result: T;

  // ...

  return result;
}
```

Тогда при вызове можно будет указать нужный тип:

```
const data = await getResult<ResponseObject>(url);
```

Избегать *any* и явно указывать типы - это ключевая идея TypeScript.